# Printing each item of a variable on a separate line in Python

Tags: python, variables, format, line

I am trying to print a list in Python that contains digits and when it prints the items in the list all print on the same line.

```
print ("{} ".format(ports))
```

here is my output

```
[60, 89, 200]
```

how can I see the result in this form:

```
60
89
200
```

I have tried `print ("\n".join(ports))` but that does not work.

Answer (score 10):

Loop over the list and print each item on a new line:

```
for port in ports:
    print(port)
```

or convert your integers to strings before joining:

```
print('\n'.join(map(str, ports)))
```

or tell `print()` to use newlines as separators and pass in the list as separate arguments with the `*` splat syntax:

```
print(*ports, sep='\n')
```

Demo:

```
>>> ports = [60, 89, 200]
>>> for port in ports:
...     print(port)
... 
60
89
200
>>> print('\n'.join(map(str, ports)))
60
89
200
>>> print(*ports, sep='\n')
60
89
200
```

Comment: That's weird that in the documentation that pops up when hovering mouse over print, it doesn't mention that we need to use * when using `sep`.

Comment: @LoMaPh: this isn't specific to `print()`. It's general Python syntax to pass in multiple positional arguments as a sequence. See [What does \*\* (double star/asterisk) and \* (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](//stackoverflow.com/q/36901)

Answer (score 6):

> i have tried print ("\n".join(ports)) but does not work.

You're very close. The only problem is that, unlike `print`, `join` doesn't automatically convert things to strings; you have to do that yourself.

For example:

```
print("\n".join(map(str, ports)))
```

… or …

```
print("\n".join(str(port) for port in ports))
```

If you don't understand either comprehensions or `map`, both are equivalent* to this:

```
ports_strs = []
for port in ports:
    ports_strs.append(str(port))
print("\n".join(ports_strs))
del ports_strs
```

In other words, `map(str, ports)` will give you the list `['60', '89', '200']`.

Of course it would be silly to write that out the long way; if you're going to use an explicit `for` statement, you might as well just `print(port)` directly each time through the loop, as in jramirez's answer.

---

* I'm actually cheating a bit here; both give you an *iterator* over a sort of "lazy list" that doesn't actually exist with those values. But for now, we can just pretend it's a list. (And in Python 2.x, it was.)

Answer (score 4):

If you are on Python 3.x:

```
>>> ports = [60, 89, 200]
>>> print(*ports, sep="\n")
60
89
200
>>>
```

Otherwise, this will work:

```
>>> ports = [60, 89, 200]
>>> for p in ports:
...     print p
...
60
89
200
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ports = [60, 89, 200]

for p in ports:
    print (p)
```